# the difference between 'danced ritual' and 'dancing ritual'

Tags: word-meaning

Some use 'dancing ritual'

> Third, the king was an active participant in the **dancing ritual**; he
>   did not sit at a high place looking down while others performed the
>   ritual.
>
> The drumming and **dancing ritual** was a new dimension to the way of life
>   of the Africans.
>
> The blast occurred as devotees gathered for a dhamal, a **dancing ritual**
>   central to the mystical Sufi tradition of Islam.

Whereas others use 'danced ritual'

> It is not easy to read the excitement of a **danced ritual** into
>   prehistoric drawings.
>
> In this particular **danced ritual**, everything has to be exact.
>
> Dancing is the oldest and most elementary form of spiritual
>   expression; it is magic in the form of a **danced ritual**.

What is your take in terms of difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a dancing ritual

is a ritual which revolves around dancing. For example, a ballerina warming up at the barre.

[image]

Whereas

> a danced ritual

is a ritual which occurs in the form of dance. For example the New Year's Ball in Vienna is a danced ritual.  The celebration is about the arrival of the New Year, but there happens to be many waltzes involved.

[image]
<sub>(source: [hofburgsilvesterball.com](https://www.hofburgsilvesterball.com/cms/upload/legrandbal/bg-debuetanten_premiere.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a substantial difference in meaning.  Both will refer to rituals that involve physical, rhythmic movement, possibly set to music.

The term "danced ritual" seems more modern and academic, and is probably a specialized term used primarily in anthropology or similar fields.  Although "dancing ritual" seems similarly stilted, and not something you would use in everyday conversation.  The more natural expression would be, "a ritual that involves dancing."

Comment: There's nothing especially "stilted" about *dancing ritual*.  I would agree that **danced** ritual is decidedly academic, and refers to the mode of expression.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  it sounds stilted to me but I'll concede it's just my opinion.